# How to check if user input data is in other than English language?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am using Facebook API in my app to do the user authentication and then saves the user data into DB. And I am using same (i.e. facebook) username for my app if it exist else I create the username using name, but the problem is that some user's don't have their display name in English. So how can I check for such input at server side?

My app is written in Asp.net.

Comment: What problems is this causing?

Comment: @shrutyzet for now we are only allowing English username so when I try to create username and saves it in DB, it saves like this ????.?????.????.?????

Comment: is this maybe a problem relating to database charset?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan I know I have set dataType to varchar instead of nvarchar, but as I said it is in the design to have only english username and I have to validate the username before saving it into DB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check if the characters are only `a, b, c...z` or `A, B, C...Z`:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex rgx = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z]+$");

if (rgx.IsMatch(inputData))
   // input data is in English alphabet; take appropriate action...
else
   // input data is not in English alphabet; take appropriate action...
```

Comment: Does English language not allowing punctuation anymore? Just don't do it this way!

Comment: @JuicyScripter: usernames don't usually contain punctuation, not even in english :p

Comment: @Razvan Even if we speak about Facebook `username` it allows use of `.` within.

Comment: @JuicyScripter: yeah, you are right and the example can easily be tweaked to account for that

Answer (score 1):

It may be overkill for this task but correct way to detect input language is using something like [Extended Linguistic Services APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317839%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or services like [Free Language Detection API](http://detectlanguage.com/)

In your case I suggesting saving user names in appropriate encoding (like `utf-8` or `utf-16`, which should be fine for user names on Facebook)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't that the usernames are in a foreign language, but rather that you are trying to store data into a database without using the appropriate character encoding (the only reason I've ever seen those `???` is when character encoding was at least one level too low for the current problem).

At a *minimum*, you should be using `utf-8`, but you probably want to use `utf-16` (or even `utf-32` if you're being really conservative). I also recommend this [mandatory reading](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

---

Determining whether a username is in English or not is impossible. There are too many possible variants on proper nouns to be able to provide any reliable metric. Then there are transplanted names and the like. You can try to detect if there are non-ASCII characters (I believe `/[^ -~]/` should match all of them — space is the lowest "typeable" character in ASCII, ~ is the highest), but then you are compensating for the unicode problem instead of letting the computer handle that gracefully.